# Как реализовать множество EditText

Tags: java, android

Нужно сделать около 30-ти *EditText*, но не так, чтобы они все были на одной странице.

Нужно по одной на странице.  Ну, например, пользователь заходит в приложение, и его просит ввести имя, он вводит имя, нажимает "далее", и тут его просит ввести фамилию, и так далее.

Каким образом можно реализовать подобное, ведь создавать для каждого компонента *layout* и *Activity*, я думаю, не лучший вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создаёте одну активити с одним `EditText`.
2. Вводите тест.
3. По нажатию на далее удаляете из него введённый тест.
4. Просите ввести что-то ещё в уже снова пустой `EditText`
5. Повторяете 2-4.

Comment: только в пункте 3 наверное надо сохранить куда то ввод перед удалением  .. позволил себе немного уточнить по пункту 1

Comment: Про третий согласен, но мне показалось, что ТС оскорбится, если я буду напоминать ему о таких очевидных вещах) Уточнение в тему. Гонитесь за значком "80 правок"? =)

Comment: Нет, значки меня не интересуют в принципе и у других я не обращаю на них внимание. Мне нравится, когда инструкция однозначна, а @Денис собирался сделать 30 активити, нужно было его остановить, пока не началось .. :)